# Uncaught TypeError despite undefined check

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am getting [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw2wR.png)

I am trying to filter by time of day, and I'm receiving the inputs from two HTML time fields.

```
export function timeBetweenFilterFn(rows, id, filterValues) {
const startVals = filterValues[0] ? filterValues[0].split(':') : undefined;
const endVals = filterValues[1] ? filterValues[1].split(':') : undefined;


const [startHour, startMinutes] = startVals ? 
        startVals.map( (val) => {
            return parseInt(val);
        })
        : undefined;
const [endHour, endMinutes] = endVals ? 
        endVals.map( (val) => {
            return parseInt(val);
        })
        : undefined;

if (startVals || endVals) {
    return rows.filter( (row) => {
        const [cellHour, cellMinutes] = row.values[id].split(':').map( (val) => {
            return parseInt(val);
        })
        if (cellHour === startHour){
            return cellMinutes >= startMinutes;
        }
        else if(cellHour === endHour){
            return cellMinutes <= endMinutes;
        }
        else{
            return cellHour >= startHour && cellHour <= endHour;
        }

    })
}
return rows;
```

}

when either the start field or end field is not given, I get the uncaught type error when I try to map the array to the new values despite the ternary check.

Comment: Well you're doing `const [startHour, startMinutes] = undefined`.

Comment: Actually you need none of this code. The benefit of the standard `hh:mm` format is that you can just lexically compare the strings, no parsing required. Then you also wouldn't have the bug where you're not testing for `endMinutes` when `startHour` and `endHour` are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `undefined` as the fallback value, you will get an error cause you are trying to get variables `[startHour, startMinutes]` and `[endHour, endMinutes]` from `undefined`, *which is not iterable*.

---

You can't try to get variables from `undefined`.

As you can see in this example made in the browser console, i get the same error, because `undefined` is not iterable.

[image]

Instead of `undefined`, try using `[]` as default value in order to avoid errors.

[image]

In this case the variables `a` and `b` will simply be `undefined`.